# How to apply fontSize to CardHeader title in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the title in `CardHeader` to 16px. I tried changing theme in App.js but it does not seem to work

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
    overrides: {
      MuiCardHeader: {
        titleTypographyProps: {
          variant:'h2'
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

In the component:

```
<CardHeader
  action={
    <IconButton color="inherit">
      <MoreHorizIcon />
    </IconButton>
  }
  title="Titletext"
/>
```

The title font still does not change. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: you can taret te element with CSS and change it manually as idea,

Comment: I want to do it the right way using Material UI React overrides

Comment: you see props `titleTypographyProps` ? you can change the size of title but with tag and not pixels

Comment: Can you give me in code? I tried this  overrides: {
        MuiCardHeader: {
          titleTypographyProps: {
            title: h1
          }
        }
      }

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you cant target the header class or id and change fontSize or
pass as props

```
titleTypographyProps={{variant:'h1' }}
```

that object acepts:`'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'subtitle1', 'subtitle2', 'body1', 'body2', 'caption', 'button', 'overline', 'srOnly', 'inherit', "display4", 'display3', 'display2', 'display1', 'headline', 'title', 'subheading'`

in your code it would be

```
<CardHeader
        action={
        <IconButton color="inherit">
            <MoreHorizIcon />
        </IconButton>
        }
        titleTypographyProps={{variant:'h1' }}
        title="Titletext"
      />
```

Comment: overrides: {
        MuiCardHeader: {
          titleTypographyProps: {
            variant:'h2'
          }
        }
      } does not work

Comment: @Dupocas he is talking about CardHeader.  tytletypographyProps is a default prop, you dont need to override that

Comment: Similarly `subheaderTypographyProps={{variant:'subtitle2' }}` can be used to customize subtitle appearance.

Answer (score 10):

In **MUI v5**, you make use of [system properties](https://mui.com/components/typography/#system-props) in `Typography` by adding a `fontSize` prop directly in `titleTypographyProps` or `subheaderTypographyProps`:

```
<CardHeader
  titleTypographyProps={{
    fontSize: 22,
  }}
  subheaderTypographyProps={{
    fontSize: 10,
  }}
  title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
  subheader="September 14, 2016"
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 9):

this piece of code worked for me:

```
<CardHeader
title={
         <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            /* Content goes here */
         </Typography>
      } />
```

notes: package: "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.2"
I use this solution because I make use of makeStyles module.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is quite old post now, but for future references anyone who stumbles upon this question might take a look at: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7521

Basically, we can use the `classes` property, which takes key/value pairs, and can add style to parts of the `<ContentHeader />` component based on that.

Example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    minWidth: 300,
    maxWidth: 500,
    margin: "10px 15px 10px 0",
  },
  headerTitle: {
    maxWidth: 300
  }
});

const CustomizedCard = () => {
  const materializeUIClasses = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={materialUIClasses.root}>
      <CardHeader 
        title={title}

        // Here we can target whatever part we need: title, subtitle, action
        classes={{
          title: materialUIClasses.headerTitle
        }} 
      />
   </Card>
}
```

Comment: This is not the only working solution also the best practice.